# Can every positive root of a Coxeter group be written as a simple root and a positive root?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, coxeter-groups

Can every positive root of a Coxeter group be written as a simple root and a positive root? I think that this is possible. For example, in type $B_2$, the set of positive roots are $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_1+\alpha_2, \alpha_1+2\alpha_2$. The positive root $\alpha_1+2\alpha_2$ can be written as $\alpha_2 + (\alpha_1+\alpha_2)$. Are there some reference about this result? Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, the simple roots cannot, but all others can. Look up "root strings" in for example Humphreys' book on Lie algebras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not always possible for general Coxeter groups, where the root systems are not required to have integral coefficients. For example, for $I_2(5)$ there is an irrational number $z$ so that the positive roots are $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\alpha_1+z\alpha_2$, $z\alpha_1+\alpha_2$, and $z\alpha_1+z\alpha_2$, with the final root being the counterexample.

However, in the integral case the simple roots are characterized as being the only positive roots $\alpha$ such that if $\beta$ is a positive root, then $\alpha-\beta$ is not a root. This can lead you to the result you want. In the non-integral case we must generalize this somewhat: $\alpha$ is simple if and only if there do not exist a positive root $\beta$ and  a positive real number $a$ such that $\alpha-a\beta$ is a positive root.

Comment: Ahh, I had assumed Weyl group in my comment due to an insufficient reading of the question.

Comment: @Matt, thank you very much. Is the following modification correct: every positive root of a Coxeter group can be written as a positive linear combination of a simple root and a positive root (that is $\beta = k_1 \alpha_i + k_2 \beta'$, where $\alpha_i$ is some simple root, $\beta'$ is a positive root, $k_1,k_2>0$)?

Comment: @LJR Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Matt Samuel, thank you very much.

Comment: @LJR You're welcome.